# Apache Tamaya CDI Extension causes startup issue in WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly

I am trying to use Apache Tamaya with the CDI extension in my project.

I have included the following libraries in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tamaya</groupId>
            <artifactId>tamaya-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.2-incubating</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tamaya.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>tamaya-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>0.2-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
```

I defined an application scoped bean that extends the `BasePropertySource`.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DatabasePropertySource extends BasePropertySource {

  ...
}
```

I am using WildFly 10. When starting the application, I get the following exception: `BeanAttributes.getTypes() may not return an empty set org.apache.tamaya.integration.cdi.ConfigurationExtension$ConverterBean`

Full stack trace

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001112: BeanAttributes.getTypes() may not return an empty set org.apache.tamaya.integration.cdi.ConfigurationExtension$ConverterBean@16d7a9db
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.attributes.ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.validateTypes(ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.attributes.ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.validateBeanAttributes(ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.addBean(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tamaya.integration.cdi.ConfigurationExtension.addConverter(ConfigurationExtension.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

2016-06-01 12:03:59,119 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "tickeos-core-web.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"tickeos-core-web.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"tickeos-core-web.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001112: BeanAttributes.getTypes() may not return an empty set org.apache.tamaya.integration.cdi.ConfigurationExtension$ConverterBean@16d7a9db
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.attributes.ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.validateTypes(ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.attributes.ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.validateBeanAttributes(ExternalBeanAttributesFactory.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.addBean(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tamaya.integration.cdi.ConfigurationExtension.addConverter(ConfigurationExtension.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
"}}
```

Even without the custom `DatabasePropertySource`, the server won't start up.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAMAYA-163